# How to export c++ class adopted template method pattern with virtual interface to python world by pybind11?

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

We have a class hierarchy which follow the template method pattern. The `Interface` class has a pure virtual method `process()`. class `AbstractImpl` inherit it and fill the `process` body with some pure virtual `stepX` method. Finally, derived class `Concrete1` implement those `stepX` method to extend custom behaviors.

```cpp
class Interface {
public:
   virtual int process() = 0;
};

class AbstractImpl : public Interface {
public:
   int process override(){
       step1();
       // do something
       step2();
   }
protected:
    virtual void step1() = 0;
    virtual void step2() = 0;
};

class Derived : public AbstractImpl {
protected:
    void step1() final {
        // do something
    }

    void step2() final {
        // do something
    }
};
```

In c++ world, i can use easily it like:

```cpp
Interface* obj = new Derived();
int res = obj->process();
```

Now we need to create some python binding for `Derived` class for some scaffolding test usage by pybind11. Ideally, in python world we could write:

```py
obj = Derived()
res = obj.process()
```

I've checked the pybind11 document class [section](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/classes.html), which provide some examples like `PYBIND11_OVERRIDE_PURE`.

However, the `Derived` class actually not derived directly from `Interface` class, and we only want to export the base `process` method but not other protected `step` method to python world.

I wonder is there anyway to export the `Derived` class and it public interface `process` to python world, without much instruive code like `PYBIND11_OVERRIDE_PURE` added?

Comment: From the example it seems like you are not planning to extend your `Derived` class any further, so maybe simply exporting only `Derived` class to python with it's 1 method `process` will work just fine?

Comment: @pptaszni exactly, i only need to export ```Derived``` class to python with ```process``` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to use your `Derived` class in your python code like this

```
obj = Derived()
res = obj.process()
```

it is just enough to export it to python as `Derived` class with `AbstractImpl` parent class and only one method `process`:

```
PYBIND11_MODULE(examplePythonModule, m) {
    py::class_<AbstractImpl>(m, "AbstractImpl")
        // no "init" for abstract class
        .def("process", &AbstractImpl::process);
    py::class_<Derived, AbstractImpl>(m, "Derived")
        .def(py::init<>());
        // process method already exported by the parent class
}
```

Add some observable behavior and check that it works. As long as you don't export any functions taking `Interface&` as argument, python doesn't even need to know about this type.